# Xubuntu excessive memory consumption

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, memory-usage

```
$ free -m
            total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          7917       7011        906          0        124        609
-/+ buffers/cache:       6276       1640
Swap:         8122       3770       4352
```

I have Xubuntu running on an HP EliteBook i5 with 8 GB of RAM.

```
$ uname -a 
Linux HP-EliteBook-8470p 3.5.0-37-generic #58~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 10
17:48:11 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Normally I have to run Vagrant (VirtualBox), Firefox (15 to 20 tabs) and NetBeans. Vagrant normally takes 1 GB, Firefox almost takes on 1 GB and it's the same for NetBeans.

This still doesn't explain why my free memory is so low. I open `htop` and I see multiple instances of X.

Anyone know what the problem might be?

Comment: Sometimes, it might be the `terminal`. I use Xuxubntu as well, and when i leave my `terminal` (`xfce4-terminal`) open, it uses about `1-4GB` of RAM. Close and open it again, or search about the `xfce4-taskmanager` to see who has taken the whole RAM.

Answer (score 1):

Quite possibly one of the apps (perhaps Firefox or Flash) gradually leak memory. I have a very similar issue with long Opera sessions. I found that the best way to deal with this is to `reboot` often enough (basically, whenever the system starts swapping).